# How to assign shift to time from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure for API. When user inputs `'morning'`, then it will get data according to that given time.

In SQL Server, table we have a `FromTime` column.

```
DECLARE @isdaytime varchar(20) = 'morning'

SELECT
    md.doctor_id, hdr.ScheduleId, md.first_name, md.last_name,
    det.FromTime, det.ToTime 
FROM
    mst_doctor md 
INNER JOIN
    DoctorScheduleHdr hdr ON hdr.DoctorId = md.doctor_id 
INNER JOIN
    DoctorScheduleDet det ON hdr.ScheduleId = det.ScheduleId
WHERE
    CASE 
        WHEN (@isdaytime = 'morning') 
            THEN det.FromTime BETWEEN CAST('09:00:00.0000000' AS time) AND CAST('11:59:00.0000000' AS time) 
    CASE 
        WHEN (@isdaytime = 'afternoon') 
            THEN det.FromTime BETWEEN CAST('12:00:00.0000000' AS time) AND CAST('14:59:00.0000000' AS time) 
    CASE 
        WHEN (@isdaytime = 'evening') 
            THEN det.FromTime BETWEEN CAST('15:00:00.0000000' AS time)  AND CAST('20:59:00.0000000' AS time)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the appropriate boolean condition in the `WHERE`clause:

```
...
where 
   ((@isdaytime = 'morning') and (det.FromTime between cast('09:00:00.0000000'as time) and cast('11:59:00.0000000'as time))) or
   ((@isdaytime = 'afternoon') and (det.FromTime between cast('12:00:00.0000000'as time) and cast('14:59:00.0000000'as time))) or 
   ((@isdaytime = 'evening') and (det.FromTime between cast('15:00:00.0000000'as time) and cast('20:59:00.0000000'as time)))
```

As an additional note, in T-SQL `CASE` is not a "Control-of-Flow" language element, it's an expression.

Comment: I want to use it as a case.

Comment: @AbhishekBorse, why do you need a `CASE`. In T-SQL `CASE` is an expression and returns single value, so a statement like `CASE WHEN condition THEN return some rows` is not a valid language construction.

Comment: @isdaytime is parameter for API. So when user selects morning/afternoon/evening i have to show doctor name according to shift. Using AND is not solving my problem.

Comment: @AbhishekBorse, if I understand the question correctly, the `@isdaytime` parameter can hold only one of these three possible values - `morning`, `afternoon` and `evening`. So, in this case, the `WHERE` clause will return the expected results.

Comment: You are right. `@isdaytime` is holding one value, which is user going to put in API. But now how can i map those possible value -`morning` , `afternoon`,`evening` to those given timestamp

Comment: @AbhishekBorse, you don't need to _map_ values. If, for example,  the `@isdaytime` parameter is equal to `morning`, only the `((@isdaytime = 'morning') and (det.FromTime between cast('09:00:00.0000000'as time) and cast('11:59:00.0000000'as time)))` part of the combined condition equals to `true` and only the rows with time values between `09:00:00` and `11:59:00` will be returned. That's the whole idea in this answer.